# interchangeability of sum and integral

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I tried to show that $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k}\ln{x}\right)\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{k}}{k}\ln{x}\,dx\right).$$

How to show that the series of functions $F_{n}(x):=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^{k}}{k}\ln{x}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Because of the factor $\ln{x}$, it is hard to me.

Give some advice. Thank you!

Comment: from $k\geq 2$, we see $|x^k\ln x|=x^{k-0.5}|\sqrt x \ln x|$, and $\sqrt x\ln x$ is bounded on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum value of $|(x^k\ln x)/k|$ on $[0,1]$ occurs at $x=(1/e)^{1/k},$ giving a value of $\dfrac{1}{ek^2}.$ Since $\sum 1/k^2 < \infty,$ the given series converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M test.

Answer (score 2):

The map $x \mapsto -x \log x$, together with $0 \log 0 := 0$, is non-negative and continuous on $[0, 1]$. From this, we find that $-F_n$ is continuous, non-negative and pointwise increasing in $n$. Moreover, its pointwise limit is

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (-F_n(x)) = \log(1-x)\log x, $$

which is continuous on $[0, 1]$. So by [*Dini's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem), this convergence is uniform.

If your ultimate goal is simply interchanging the order of integral and summation, uniform convergence is a bit redundant, in view of the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem_3).